# Multiplying vectors with unit of measure in F#

Tags: f#, vector, measure

I've written the following

```
[<Measure>]
type m

[<Measure>]
type s

[<Measure>]
type v = m/s

type Vector3<[<Measure>] 'a> =
    {
    X : float<'a>
    Y : float<'a>
    Z : float<'a>
    }
    static member (*)
        (v:Vector3<'a>,f:float<'b>):Vector3<'a*'b> =
        { X = v.X*f; Y = v.Y*f ; Z = v.Z * f}
```

Now I'm trying to use it this way:

```
let next_pos (position:Vector3<m> , velocity: Vector3<m/s> ,dt : float<s>  ->  Vector3<m>) =
     position + (velocity * dt)
```

It gives me a compiler error, but I'm pretty sure the measure unit are expressed right.
What's my mistake?

Comment: your units of measure don't look right to me. With (velocity * dt) you're multiplying a velocity (m/s) with the return type of dt, which is in meters (m). The result is m^2/s, not m as you want to have.

Comment: Note that you could also just let the compiler infer a more general type: `let nextpos(v:Vector3<_>, v':Vector3<_>, dv) = v + v' * dv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you tried to use for specifying the return type was incorrect. It should look like this:

```
let next_pos (position:Vector3<m>, velocity:Vector3<m/s>, dt:float<s>) : Vector3<m> = 
  position + (velocity * dt)
```

To specify that the function returns a value of type `Vector3<m>`, you need to add type annotation to the result, which is done by writing `let foo <arguments> : T = <expr>`. When adding type annotations to parameters, these need to be parenthesized (so the syntax is not ambiguous). As noted by Paolo in a comment, your use of `->` was saying that `dt` is a function, because the annotation `float<s> -> Vector3<m>` was attached to the parameter `dt`.

To make the code compile, I also had to add an implementation of `(+)` operator to your `Vector3`, but I assume you have that already (and just left it out when posting the question).

Comment: yes..I already defined + operator, and thanks.. this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this way (but I'm not sure about the reason).

```
let next_pos (position:Vector3<m> , velocity: Vector3<m/s> ,dt : float<s> ) =
     position + (velocity * dt)
```

It seems that the compiler fails if I explicetly define the return type. If I remove it seems able to infer the correct type anyway.
But why this?

In addition to that, there are situations in which name clashes in type declaration force me to explictely specify the return type. So I don't think this is the right solution in the end.

Comment: in fact now you've changed dt from a function returning a position(m) to a time (s). Now your units of measure are fine, because velocity (m/s) * dt (s) are indeed a position (m)

Comment: @Paolo Falabella: thanks I think I begin to understand. With -> Vector3<m> I was trying to express the return value of next_pos but I think this way I'm defining the return value of dt, right?

Comment: esatto :) If Vector3<m> is the return value of next_pos, the explicit syntax is:  `let next_pos (position:Vector3<m> , velocity: Vector3<m/s> ,dt : float<s> ) : Vector3<m> `

Comment: @Paolo Falabella: thank you very much, your comments help me to figure out the problem